# Access to value in ASP.NET Model, not in database, for linq query

Tags: linq

I'm building the front-end of this web app in Angular 5, and back-end in ASP.NET 4.6.1, Entity Framework 6.2.0. I built a POST http call in Angular to post an int (from a option dropdown list) to a model in the back-end. This model called `ViewModelLocation` is supposed to store this value (the location number) so that I can access the location number in a linq query.

Therefore, I do not want this value to post to the database (no table for this in database) because I only want to use this number to filter, and get all students at the location number (selected in Angular). The post call seems to work, but I do not know how to write this linq query (since this number is not in my database) and return the students. I may be going about this the wrong way (?) I also would like to see what this value is once it posts to the back-end.

Here is my attempt at the linq, in the StudentsController...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using ContentMastAPI.Models;

namespace ContentMastAPI.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : ApiController
    {
        private Model1 db = new Model1();

        // GET: api/Students
        public IQueryable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            // TRYING TO RETURN ALL STUDENTS FROM SELECTED LOCATION
            var returnStudents = db.Students.Where(s => s.location == ViewModelLocation.OptionSelectId);

            return returnStudents;

            return db.Students;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContentMastAPI.Models
{
    public class ViewModelLocation
    {
        [Key]
        public int OptionSelectId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really separate your view models and your database models.
Right now your get method has no parameter (e.g. it takes nothing in). You need to add parameter to be able to use it in your filtering.

```
// No need for returning IQueryable since receiver will have no use of it.
public IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> GetStudents(int locationId)
{
    var entities = db.Students.Where(s => s.LocationId == locationId);
    return entities.Select(e => new StudentViewModel
    {
         // Map your entity properties to view model properties
    };
}
```

Also, consider changing your location property to Pascal casing ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, although my code is still not working.  All I want to do is pass in a number, store it temporarily in the server (NOT in a SQL database), then use that number to filter in a Linq query to a SQL database, and send the query results to the view.

Comment: I reworked my query, per your suggestions (using the names from my code above), no errors in Visual Studio, but I have a server error running the app... "405 Method Not Allowed..."  I'm not sure what you mean by separating view models from database models.  This is the first time I've created a model that did not connect to a database -which is why I'm not sure how to do this.  Do I need a  DbContext for my model?  A different type of controller?  I feel like Angular is complicating this too.

Comment: You should make a GET-request with locationId as parameter instead of a POST (as you mentioned you are doing in your question). Thus, the "405 Method Not Allowed" error.